# Pass a variable on a function inside v-on:click or @click (Vue.js)

Tags: button, vue.js, vue-component, quasar-framework, quasar

I'm developing a system with vuejs right now. I would like to know if how am I going to pass a variable value inside v-on:click or @click? this is my code:

The props.row contains an object with a key of '_id' and what I want to do is to pass that to the function 'view'.

```js
<q-td key="status" :props="props">
  <q-btn
    color="primary"
    label="view"
    v-on:click="view({{props.row._id}})"
    icon="remove_red_eye"
  /> 
</q-td>
```

The program crashes.

Comment: Could you provide some code, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in! Just resolve my own problem. lol this is what I did:

```js
<q-td key="status" :props="props">
  <q-btn
    color="primary"
    label="view"
    @click.native="view(props.row._id)"
    v-on
    icon="remove_red_eye"
  />
</q-td>
```

Comment: But if you have another solution, please do still comment it for future use

Answer (score 5):

You can directly pass _id in @click without using .native.
Do not confuse native events with the Vue events emitted by the component. They are different things.

```js
<q-td key="status" :props="props">
  <q-btn 
    color="primary"
    label="view"
    @click="view(props.row._id)"
    icon="remove_red_eye"
  />
</q-td>
```

See this Document(https://quasar-framework.org/guide/quasar-upgrade-guide.html#Some-components-need-native-modifier-for-events-now) for more detail.